# Upload a csv file using google scripts to bigquery fails

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I did a google script to automatically upload a csv file to bigquery. It was a small file (5mb), and it worked out. Now, I'm trying to upload a 150MB csv file with the very same script, and I always get a "server error". Is it supposed to work until 1GB, isn't it?

I appreciate your help!

Albert

Comment: Do you have a BigQuery job id for the server error? It is possible that you're getting a timeout on the client side from google apps script.

Comment: Hi Jordan, it works with smaller files, so, I don't think this is the problem. I'm trying to figure it out a way to upload (not me, others users, so, we cannot use bigquery UI) a large csv file to process. I'm thinking on cloud storage, but I cannot find the way either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bigquery has 1GB limit but the Google Apps Script UrlFetch Post Size can be maximum upto 10MB. You can not POST 100MB file using Apps Script UrlFetch

Check for Quota limits here.

- https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard

Comment: In this case...what do you suggest? I tried to build an Engine Java App, but I'm stuck on eclipse setup. But, is it an easy way to upload a 200mb file to cloud storage through an UI? for example? Cloud storage interface is not useful because it only runs with my user, I want other people to be able to upload.

Comment: There are  a lot of Third Party Tools available which work with Big Query. You may use any of those. http://goo.gl/0XbpC9