# Upload automatically a large file for bigquery processing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm planning and App to process a large file (150MB) for bigquery analysis, without using any UI. I've tried with google apps scripts, but I cannot upload this files, server error. Is there any way to upload throught scripts to google cloud storage, for example? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a very simple html form allowing users to select files and send it to a specific bucket. Something like this works for me.

```
<form action="http://storage.googleapis.com/Put_your_own_bucket_name_here" 
      method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">Select a local file to send to cloud storage:
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="${filename}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="Use your OK URL here" />
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

The ${filename} means the uploaded filename will be used.

If you want unauthenticated users to send files be sure to modify bucket permissions. You can do that from cloud storage browser within developers console for your project.

Take a look to https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#postobject for complete reference.

Answer (score 5):

From the answer on your other question: [Upload a csv file using google scripts to bigquery fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681142/upload-a-csv-file-using-google-scripts-to-bigquery-fails), it sounds like the limit you're hitting is the post size on google apps script is limited to 10 MB. So I don't know of any way around this using Google Apps Script (even Google Cloud Storage will have the same limitation).

You said that you don't want to use a UI... can you use Python? If you install the [Google Cloud SDK](https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/), you can use the `bq` command line client to run the BigQuery install, or you can upload the file to Google Cloud Storage via the `gsutil` tool. Do these solve your use case? If not, can you provide more information about your use case? Where does this 150MB file live? Will you need to upload it just once or for each user? (on your other question you mention that you want other users to be able to upload ... do they all use the same file or a different one? Is it static or is it changing? Can you load it once to BigQuery and then copy the table for each user that needs it?

Comment: Hi Jordan, I really appreciate your help. I want to build an online service, where clients upload a different csv file each, and we analyze with bigquery. As this is a 150MB file, I cannot figure it out a way to automatically get bigquery script to run it. Even if I upload it to any server, no way to "send" from this place to bigquery through code...

Comment: Where do your clients upload the file to? Can you have them upload it to Google Cloud Storage? That way in your BigQuery import job you could just point BigQuery at the GCS path and don't have to move any bytes over the network.